# Bias-variance decomposition with sklearn BaggingRegressor

Tags: regression, variance, scikit-learn, bias, bagging

There is an example given on the [Scikit-Learn site](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_bias_variance.html) that compares the bias-variance decomposition of the rmse of a single SVR model against a bagging ensemble. Unfortunately, the data is being generated through a function f(x). My question is how I could make it work on a real regression example for which I have an array `X_train` of `shape = [n_samples_train, n_features]`, an array `X_test` of `shape = [n_samples_test, n_features]` and a target array `y_train` of `shape = [n_samples_train]`.

Obviously, I don't have access to the target array `y_test`. Ultimately I could instead use a fold of the training data that I dedicate to validation. Also, their estimate of the variance is done by calling `f(X_test): y_bias = (f(X_test) - np.mean(y_predict, axis=1)) ** 2`.

What would the equivalent of calling `f(X_test)` in a real example be? In the case I use a validation fold, would that simply be the target `y_validation` array?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that in real problems you don't have f(x) or y_test because it is what you try to predict.

The best way to deal with Bias-Variance trade-off is to analyse the model complexity. For example, in Random Forest you can increase the n_estimators or max_depth increasing the variance and reducing the bias.

[image]

As you can see in the image, after max_depth=15 you don't have an improvement in the score. Give a higher value to max_depth will increase the complexity and the variance without a better score, hence 15 could be a good "Trade-Off".

In the other hand, you can split your data set in Train and Test datasets, in this case, you still don't have the f(x) but at least you will have y_test (real values)